# insert conditionally get row id?

Tags: .net, sql, sqlite, dapper

I want to create a thread but only if the subject is unique in that section. Then I want to get the row id of the thread. How do I write it safely? My thoughts were something like

```
connection.Query<long>(@"insert into thread(section, subject, body) 
    select @section,@subject,@body
    where not exists in (select 1 from thread where section=@section and subject=@subject;
    select last_insert_rowid()", new {...}).First();
```

The problem is I have no idea if last_insert_rowid something from the past or from my insert statement. How do I write this query safely

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help on the SQLite front. If you know the SQL needed, I can advise on any dapper.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I thought there would be some sql idiom for conditional insert/return id. I'm shocked no one replied. I happen to know sqlite will lock the values I read provided that they are in a transaction. I guess I'll do a multiple queries/execute

Answer (score 1):

If understand correctly you can use `OR IGNORE` syntax. In order for it to work you have to have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `section` and `subject`

```
CREATE TABLE thread
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
 section INT, 
 subject TEXT(128), 
 body TEXT(256),
 UNIQUE (section, subject));
```

Now to ignore a row if it violates one of constraints

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO thread (section, subject, body)
VALUES (1, 'Subject1', 'Body1');
```

Now if insert succeeded then `LAST_INSERT_ROWID()` will return an id for the inserted row, but if it was a duplicate for `section` and `subject` insert failed it will return `0`.

Comment: Incorrect. It appears that my `insert or ignore into ...; select last_insert_rowid()` returned 1 instead of 0. I have a unique contain which prevented the insert but it didn't return 0.

Comment: It means I suppose that you first made a successful insert in the same session and then second one was ignored. Now to overcome this one suggestion would be to store a value of `LAST_INSERT_ROWID()` before insert then after insert call it again and compare with stored value. If the current value is greater then stored then you have a successful insert and a new id. BTW you can't use multi-insert. You should issue one insert statement at a time.